# parsing JSONObject to custom class

Tags: java, php, android, json, string

my data from my custom class isn't showing.

I get my JSON object from php script and I store it in String `result`, then I try to insert it to my custom class `Planets`
from that class I call specific variable by get Method but it doesn't show in my TextView `result_tv`

here is code:

```
String jsonString = result;
Gson gson = new Gson();
Planets seznamPlanet = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Planets.class);
this.result_tv.setText(seznamPlanet.getPlanetName());
//this.result_tv.setText(jsonString); this works
```

my class is:

```
public class Planets {
    public String name;
    public Integer size;
    public Integer o2;
    public Integer atmosphere;

    public String getPlanetName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getPlanetSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public Integer getPlanetO2() {
        return o2;
    }

    public Integer getPlanetAtmosphere() {
        return atmosphere;
    }
}
```

and JSON object inside result string looks like this:

```
    {"Planets":[{"name":"Earth","size":"3","o2":"1","atmosphere":"1"},{"name":"Mars","size":"8","o2":"0","atmosphere":"0"}]}
```

Comment: You need one more class which contains the list of planets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your `Planets` class to `Planet` (to avoid conflict)

```
public class Planet {
  public String name;
  public Integer size;
  public Integer o2;
  public Integer atmosphere;
}
```

Create another class named `PlanetsList`

```
public class PlanetsList {
    List<Planet> Planets; //rename was useful so we don't have List<Planets> Planets
}
```

Then call gson like so:

```
PlanetsList seznamPlanet = gson.fromJson(jsonString, PlanetsList.class);
```

Comment: isnt there a typo in `Planets seznamPlanet = gson.fromJson(jsonString, PlanetsList.class);`  because Planets isnt class

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
 public class Planets {
    public Planet[] planets;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (new Gson().toJson(this));
    }

    public final class Planet {
        public String name;
        public Integer size;
        public Integer o2;
        public Integer atmosphere;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return (new Gson().toJson(this));
        }
    }
}
```